# Selection.Find.Execute doesn't work correctly with Word 2013

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote a macro for Word 2003 to remove undesired "carriage return" and replace them with spaces.

So, after selectig the piece of text, I run the macro and the "carriage return" in the selection were replaced.

But under Word 2013, even if I select only a few rows, the replecement take place throughout the document.

This is my code:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = " "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "  "
    .Replacement.Text = " "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

**EDIT**

I've tried with the macro recorder and I've got the same code.
Furthermore the command worked on the selection during recording but throughout the document while executing the macro.

Is this a bug? Is there any workaround?

Comment: have you tried naming your selected range once at the start of your script, and then only adress by that Name?

Comment: @RealCheeseLord I don't know how to do that. If it works, it could be the answer. Can you help me?

Comment: try `Set myrange = Selection` and the replace every following `Selection` with `myrange`

Comment: @RealCheeseLord Sorry, it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: no Need to be sorry, but how does it not work? does `Set myrange = Selection` not work, or does the whole Thing still go over the whole workbook

Comment: @RealCheeseLord The code still works on the whole text. Look: it isn't Excel it's Word!

Comment: Oh, ok, but still. I googled a Little and try: `.Wrap = wdFindStop` instead of  `.Wrap = wdFindAsk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could probably be `.Wrap = wdFindAsk`, since this enables a prompt after the search of your `Selection` which asks you wether the search should be extended to the whole Document. But if you run the macro, the prompt does not appear and defaults to `Search the whole Document`, so your whole Document is checked.

`.Wrap = wdFindStop` should disable the prompt, and stop your replacement after the end of your `Selection` is reached.

See: [Wrap property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224337%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: It works. I'll give you the bounty as soon as possible. But I think the prompt answer set by `wdFindStop` is `No` because the question is about searching out of the selection. Please check it and give more explanations. Thanks

Comment: Very nice! my prompt basically asks: "would you like to search the rest of the document" so the answer `NO` should be the same as `.Wrap = wdFindStop`. but I changed the wording so that it is more clear hopefully

Comment: I gave you the bounty, but I think the answer could be improved by specifying why `wdFindAsk` doesn't work correctly under Word 2013. Under Word 2003, the code asks if user wants to find/replace throughout the document or only the selection.

Comment: Hi @genespos  thanks for the bounty.  I've been looking for documentation on the prompt, but can't find any... The `.Wrap` only states `After searching the selection or range, Microsoft Word displays a message asking whether to search the remainder of the document.` not a word about any default-values